# Core data and @unionOfSets

Tags: cocoa, core-data

Im having trouble using the @unionOfSets on my core-data objects.

I have a subclass of nsmanagedobject called list. There is a to-many relationship from list to listElements. and each listElement has a one-to-one relationship with a file.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSApp valueForKeyPath:@"delegate.mainWindowController.sidebarViewController.arrayController.selection.list.listElement"]);
```

Prints the set of listElements as expected

```
2010-03-24 18:11:15.844 Pirouette[7459:80f] Relationship objects for {(
<PRPlaylistElement: 0x10484c0> (entity: PRPlaylistElement; id: 0x10a71b0 <x-coredata://1EE9CEAD-E006-4487-8AA7-47764B87A91C/PRPlaylistElement/p108> ; data: <fault>),
<PRPlaylistElement: 0x1048a10> (entity: PRPlaylistElement; id: 0x10ac7d0 <x-coredata://1EE9CEAD-E006-4487-8AA7-47764B87A91C/PRPlaylistElement/p153> ; data: <fault>),
<PRPlaylistElement: 0x1048460> (entity: PRPlaylistElement; id: 0x10acf60 <x-coredata://1EE9CEAD-E006-4487-8AA7-47764B87A91C/PRPlaylistElement/p157> ; data: <fault>),
<PRPlaylistElement: 0x1047c60> (entity: PRPlaylistElement; id: 0x10a6850 <x-coredata://1EE9CEAD-E006-4487-8AA7-47764B87A91C/PRPlaylistElement/p105> ; data: <fault>)
```

However when I try to get the set of file for each of the listElements.

```
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSApp valueForKeyPath:@"delegate.mainWindowController.sidebarViewController.arrayController.selection.list.listElement.@unionOfSets.file"]);
```

I get the following error

```
2010-03-24 18:41:20.075 Pirouette[7616:80f] An uncaught exception was raised
2010-03-24 18:41:20.082 Pirouette[7616:80f] [<NSCFSet 0x1056e90> valueForKeyPath:]: this class does not implement the unionOfSets operation.
2010-03-24 18:41:20.086 Pirouette[7616:80f] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '[<NSCFSet 0x1056e90> valueForKeyPath:]: this class does not implement the unionOfSets operation.'
```

Confused because I thought to-many relationships in core-data were NSSets.

also to note

```
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSApp valueForKeyPath:@"delegate.mainWindowController.sidebarViewController.arrayController.selection.list.listElement.file"]);
```

gives the following

```
2010-03-24 18:16:45.843 Pirouette[7505:80f] {(
<PRSong: 0x10a9c10> (entity: PRSong; id: 0x104a8d0 <x-coredata://1EE9CEAD-E006-4487-8AA7-47764B87A91C/PRSong/p123> ; data: <fault>),
<PRSong: 0x10a00f0> (entity: PRSong; id: 0x1049b20 <x-coredata://1EE9CEAD-E006-4487-8AA7-47764B87A91C/PRSong/p128> ; data: <fault>),
<PRSong: 0x10ac480> (entity: PRSong; id: 0x10476a0 <x-coredata://1EE9CEAD-E006-4487-8AA7-47764B87A91C/PRSong/p145> ; data: <fault>),
<PRSong: 0x1099cd0> (entity: PRSong; id: 0x104a380 <x-coredata://1EE9CEAD-E006-4487-8AA7-47764B87A91C/PRSong/p120> ; data: <fault>))}
```

however for some reason I cant bind the contentSet of a nsarraycontroller to it.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `@unionOfArrays` rather than `@unionOfSets`. As the error indicates, this is an array operation rather than a set one.

Comment: KevinD: “Confused because I thought to-many relationships in core-data were NSSets.” They are. That's why your log output says “NSCFSet” as the receiver of the `valueForKeyPath:` message. As Chuck says, you asked this set for an array operation, so a set-does-not-support-array-operations exception is what you got.

Comment: I don't see `@unionOfArrays` in the question (edited out?!). Anyway, the `@unionOf..` operators work on arrays. If you need to use these operators on a set, use the `@distinctUnionOf...` variants.